# Including a value that has a " in it in an IF statement

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is it possible to do the following in excel:

If the length of A1 is equal to 1, return error. Else, return =@asdf.Template("VariableName")?

Like this:

```
=IF(LEN(D1)=1,"error","=@asdf.Template("VariableName")")
```

The @ is a function made with a plugin in Excel and I need to use this function. Really, the only problem that I have is that the " is included in this function, around VariableName. Anyone that knows a workaround? The only one that I have found so far was to write =@asdf.Template("VariableName") in another cell (for example K4) and refer to it, like this:

```
=IF(LEN(D1)=1,"error",K4)
```

But this is not a accepted workaround for my case, unfortunately.

Kind regards

Comment: `=IF(LEN(D1)=1,"error","=@asdf.Template(""VariableName"")")`

Comment: Thanks for you answer! Just tried this, however I cannot use it because then it does not execute the @ function.

Comment: Are you sure you do not just need: `=IF(LEN(D1)=1,"error",@asdf.Template("VariableName"))`?

Comment: Omg it worked, thank you so much, I cannot mark your answer as correct though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formula nested inside other formula do not need the `=` and are not text strings, they just need to be nested:

```
=IF(LEN(D1)=1,"error",@asdf.Template("VariableName"))
```